# Bundle statements in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, usability

How can I combine/bundle statements for further use and better handling? For example some assignments like this which would be used many times more in future calls of the routine.

```
ADDR_PC     <= "0000000000";
ADDR_OP_A   <= "00000";
ADDR_OP_B   <= "00000";             
OP_CODE     <= OP_NOP;  
OP_IMMED    <= IMMED_NULL;
WE_SREG     <= "00000"; -- S V N C Z
```

Into something like this.

```
NOP = {ADDR_PC <= "00000000", ADDR_OP_A <= "00000", ...}
```

I don't know if there are any possibilities to do that in VHDL. Any tip would be helpful.

Comment: Is NOP a constant or a signal? Is OP_CODE an enum?

Answer (score 6):

Records and/or aggregates:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity op_decoded is
end entity;

architecture foo of op_decoded is
    -- These declarations probably want to be in a package
    constant IMMED_NULL:    std_logic_vector (8 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    constant OP_NOP:        std_logic_vector (5 downto 0) := (others => '0');

    type decode_op is 
        record 
            PC:         std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
            OP_A:       std_logic_vector (4 downto 0);
            OP_B:       std_logic_vector (4 downto 0);
            OP_CODE:    std_logic_vector (5 downto 0);
            OP_IMMED:   std_logic_vector (8 downto 0);
            WE_SREG:    std_logic_vector (4 downto 0);  -- S V N C Z
        end record;

        constant NOP:  decode_op :=  (
                PC => "00000000", 
                OP_A => "00000", 
                OP_B => "00000",
                OP_CODE => OP_NOP,
                OP_IMMED => IMMED_NULL,
                WE_SREG => "00000"
            );
    -- actual signals
    signal ADDR_PC:    std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
    signal ADDR_OP_A:  std_logic_vector (4 downto 0);
    signal ADDR_OP_B:  std_logic_vector (4 downto 0);
    signal OP_CODE:    std_logic_vector (5 downto 0);
    signal OP_IMMED:   std_logic_vector (8 downto 0);
    signal WE_SREG:    std_logic_vector (4 downto 0);

    signal pipe1:       decode_op;
    signal pipe_disc:   decode_op;

begin
    (ADDR_PC, ADDR_OP_A, ADDR_OP_B, OP_CODE, OP_IMMED, WE_SREG) <= NOP;

    pipe1 <= NOP;

    pipe_disc <= (pipe1.PC, pipe1.OP_A, pipe1.OP_B, pipe1.OP_CODE,
                  pipe1.OP_IMMED, pipe1.WE_SREG);

end architecture;
```

This analyzes, elaborates and simulates (showing it's syntactically and semantically correct).

There's also an aggregate target with an aggregate right hand side (with the type provided):

```
     (ADDR_PC, ADDR_OP_A, ADDR_OP_B, OP_CODE, OP_IMMED, WE_SREG) <= 
     decode_op'(pipe1.PC, pipe1.OP_A, pipe1.OP_B, pipe1.OP_CODE,
                pipe1.OP_IMMED, pipe1.WE_SREG);
```

Answer (score 4):

VHDL has records (C calls it struct).

Declaration example:

```
type T_MY_RECORD is record
  Member1  : STD_LOGIC;
  Member2  : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
end record;

signal mySignal1  : T_MY_RECORD;
signal mySignal2  : T_MY_RECORD;
```

Usage examples:

```
mySignal1  <= (
  Member1 => '1',
  Member2 => x"12FC"
);
mySignal2.Member1 <= '0';
```

Records can be nested, e.g. for the flags.

Answer (score 2):

Records and/or aggregates are one possibility, but and alternative is to declare a procedure in the process where the signals are driven, and then call the procedure, like:

```
process (clk_i) is
  procedure NOP is
  begin
    ADDR_PC     <= "0000000000";
    ADDR_OP_A   <= "00000";
    ADDR_OP_B   <= "00000";
    OP_CODE     <= OP_NOP;
    OP_IMMED    <= IMMED_NULL;
    WE_SREG     <= "00000"; -- S V N C Z
  end procedure;
begin
  if rising_edge(clk_i) then
    ...
    NOP;
    ...
  end if;
end process;
```

This work both for simulation and synthesizable code.